# What is the difference between using () and not using () in creating class instance

Tags: c++, class, object, constructor, initialization

I wrote a class like this

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

class Resource
{
    public:
        Resource(){ cout << "allocated\n";}
        ~Resource(){ cout << "deleted\n";}
};
```

Then inside `int main()` I create 2 instances of the class

```
int main()
{
    Resource* p1 = new Resource();
    Resource* p2 = new Resource;
}
```

What is the difference between `new Resource` and `new Resource()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **parentheses** do make a difference! As @songyuanyao pointed out: you invoke *value initialisation* with the use of parentheses, and default initialisation without it. For a class type like your `Resource` you won't see any difference. The constructor is called in both cases.

However, if you have a fundamental data type such as `int` the difference is more significant:

```
int a{};
int b;
```

`a` will have value 0 because it is value initialised (with 0 by default). `b`, however, will have a garbage value, i.e. an unitialiased value. That's why it's considered bad practice to use uninitialised variables because it could lead to unintended consequences.

---

It's worth adding that since C++11, we have a uniform way of intialising variables using braces: `{}`. It removes previous distinctions for fundamental types, aggregate and non-aggregate types, arrays and standard containers.

Answer (score 4):

`new Resource()` performs [value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization), `new Resource` performs [default initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization), they have the same effect here, i.e. the object is initialized by the user-provided default constructor.

For non-class types, or class type with non-user-provided default constructor, their behaviors are different; for value-initialization, the object will be [zero-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) (firstly, then default-initialized if the default constructor of the class type is non-trivial).

> ...
>
> 2. if T is a class type with a default constructor that is neither
>    user-provided nor deleted (that is, it may be a class with an
>    implicitly-defined or defaulted default constructor), the object is
>    [zero-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) and then it is [default-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) if it has a
>    non-trivial default constructor;
>
> ...
>
> 4. otherwise, the object is [zero-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization).